# Teradata syntax?

Tags: sql, teradata

is there syntax like

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <TABLE_NAME> ON | OFF  ------- SQL SERVER
```

in teradata ??

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, in Teradata you can only set the value for an `IDENTITY`column if it was created specified as `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`.

If the column was created with the `GENERATED ALWAYS`option, no matter the value you set, Teradata will generate a value for that column.

There are other implications of choosing one or the other. More information on this [link](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1184_111A/Create_Table-Details.012.045.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option to switch on/off identity column value generation but there are options like `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` and `GENERATED ALWAYS` which can conditionally control value generation

Answer (score 0):

We do not have that kind of syntax in Teradata because Teradata handles that differently and it is configured in Column Level. Below is as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE table01 (
  col_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    (START WITH 1
     INCREMENT BY 1
     MAXVALUE 1000
     NO CYCLE
     ),
  name VARCHAR(10)
)PRIMARY INDEX(col_id);
```

Key points are below:

- `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` - This means that you may or may not insert a value for this column. Meaning, You can insert your own value in this column or if you insert a new row and did not specify a value for this column, a system generated value will be placed to it instead of NULL. You can change it to `GENERATED ALWAYS` so the system will always decide which values to be inserted to this column.
- `START WITH` - Starting Value and also the Lowest Value
- `INCREMENT BY` - the Distance between the previous value and the next value
- `MAXVALUE` - Highest Value
- `NO CYCLE` - Specify this if you do not want the same value to be repeated

Please note that using this feature may restrict you from using some Teradata Utilities and other features as well. For more information, please refer [here](https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1184-160K/ats1472241338116.html)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for example

ID_COL INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE -2147483647 MAXVALUE 100000000 NO CYCLE)